# Python - UDP socket Check response from server

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I have a basic client/server program. The server sends a timestamp to the client. I want to check to see if the client has responded with message and if not, resend the request. How would I go about this?

```
while 1:
    wait = "True"

    line = raw_input("Press enter to get the time or \"STOP\" to exit: ")
    if line == "STOP":
            break
    print "Waiting for response......"
    s.sendto(line, (servAddr,servPort))
    line, server = s.recvfrom(256)
    while wait:         // Obviously wrong, but pseudo 
            if line == "":
                    print 'Send another'
                    wait = False

    print (line)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need either `socket.settimeout()` or `select` module.

With `.settimeout()` you can tell socket to raise `socket.timeout` exception if it didn't receive any data within the specified timeframe. This is good enough if your server only has to deal with one client (one client per thread/process/greenlet/whatever also works). If you want your server to do something while waiting for client to respond and you're not using any threading/asynchronous framework, you'll probably have to write a bit more code as you'll want to set zero timeout and track the time to re-send the message manually.

`select` module provides you with tools to listen to multiple sockets with a common timeout.